# Удалить елемент в jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно удалить весь `item` при нажатии на кнопку "Удалить"? Этих итемов может быть неограниченное количество.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="right floated content">
      <a class="ui red basic button del-bookmark" data-bk="{{ book.id }}" data-pg="{{bookmark.page_id}}">Удалить</a>
    </div>
    <i class="book icon bookmark-link"></i>

    <div class="content bookmark-link">
      <a href="../book/{{book.id}}?page={{bookmark.page_id}}">Страница {{bookmark.page_id}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А что это за шаблонизатор? Не angular?

Comment: @vp_arth django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".del-bookmark").click(function(){ 
  $(this).closest(".item").remove(); 
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант:

```js
$(".del-bookmark").click(function (e) { 
    removeEl(e.target);
    return false;
});

function removeEl(el) {
    $(el).parent().parent().remove(); 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
    <div class="right floated content">
      <a class="ui red basic button del-bookmark" data-bk="{{ book.id }}" data-pg="{{bookmark.page_id}}">Удалить</a>
    </div>
    <i class="book icon bookmark-link"></i>

    <div class="content bookmark-link">
      <a href="../book/{{book.id}}?page={{bookmark.page_id}}">Страница {{bookmark.page_id}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну и ещё до кучи:

template:

```
<div class="item" id="item_{{book.id}}_{{bookmark.page_id}}">
<div class="right floated content">
  <a class="ui red basic button del-bookmark" data-bk="{{ book.id }}" data-pg="{{bookmark.page_id}}">Удалить</a>
</div>
<i class="book icon bookmark-link"></i>

<div class="content bookmark-link">
  <a href="../book/{{book.id}}?page={{bookmark.page_id}}">Страница {{bookmark.page_id}}</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".del-bookmark").click(function(){ 
  $('#item_'+$(this).data('bk')+'_'+$(this).data('pg')).remove();
  return false; 
});
```